# How do I implement the Google Places API in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, google-places-api

I'm am trying to develop an app that allows users to locate nearby establishments by implementing the Google Places API. However, there are not any comprehensive tutorials/samples on how to accomplish this. I have been able to piece together some code, but I still don't know how to parse the results and and subsequently display them on my overlay. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know where more specifically where the issue is (parsing the results or placing the pins)?  What types of errors are you seeing?

For parsing Places API results, there's a tutorial at:
https://developers.google.com/academy/apis/maps/places/autocomplete-android

The following code from the tutorial should help you get started with parsing results.  The JSON returned for the Autocomplete and Search APIs are similar, but not the same.  Be sure to follow the format at https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceSearchResults.

```
private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleApp";

private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

private static final String API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY";

private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&components=country:uk");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    try {
        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

        // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
        resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

Comment: could you look over my edit.  I don't know if I'm making progress or just becoming more confused.